# Naive reverse string iteration infinite loop and/or assertion failure C++ / Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, for-loop, infinite-loop, assertion

I am trying to reverse iterate through a string, but am getting assertion failure for the [] operator in the latest VS.

```
int foo() {
    std::string s = "s";
    for (int i = (s.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        std::cout << s[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Commenting out the cout line gives infinite loop warning and indeed enters infinite loop:

```
int foo2() {
    std::string s = "s";
    for (int i = (s.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        //std::cout << s[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Iterating forwards works just fine with or without anything in the for loop:

```
int bar() {
    std::string s = "s";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << s[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using the C++14 standard and the same code used to work on other compilers/older versions of VS. The same problem exists for any string size (although that should be irrelevant). I understand I could modify the code to use and dereference pointer instead of using int, but want to understand why this doesn't work anymore, why is it unsafe or incorrect, or what else am I missing. Thanks!

Comment: I do not see how this for loop for (int i = (s.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) { can be an infinite for loop when s.size() is not equal to 0.

Comment: *but want to understand why this doesn't work anymore* -- Probably didn't work ever, and you were just (un)lucky it did.  That's what undefined behavior can bring.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Where do you have found here undefined behavior?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow -- Just reading the commenters statement -- *I am using the C++14 standard and the same code used to work on other compilers/older versions of VS*

Comment: Are you sure this is where your problem is? There isn't really any issue in your code other then converting `std::size_t` to `int`, and your code examples work correctly in gcc/clang/msvc for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could it be that your int defaults to being unsigned and therefore decrementing when i=0 resuts in a high value ?

As @PeteBecker mentioned, int should be signed and should not overflow. However my guess is that your actual code does not use int.

Comment: i is not supposed to decrement past 0

Comment: No. `int` is always signed. It's just `char` that can be either signed or unsigned.

Comment: @PeteBecker: agreed, but I'm guessing his minimal example is not the one that loops infinitely and that in his actual code he is using a size_t i.

Comment: @gchapuis -- you can edit your answer to say that.

Comment: @PeteBecker Here you go :)

Answer (score 0):

> *Commenting out the cout line gives infinite loop warning and indeed enters infinite loop*

`s.size()` is an `unsigned long` so it can never be less than `0`. The behavior of narrowing conversion due to assignment of `unsigned long` to `int` is implementation defined behavior though it should not be a problem when assigning `unsigned long` value 0 to `int`, at least I wouldn't think so, but who knows, MSVC does have its quirks.

It appears the compiler is smart enough to predict that there cannot be an infinite loop when this particular body of the `for` loop is present, which leads me to believe that an exception may be thrown when accessing the array, perhaps out of bounds access.

Using the debugger to track the value of `i` is your best bet to understand what is going on.

Comment: Where is there in the loop  used a negative value of i?!

Comment: The thing is that i is not supposed to go past 0 at all per the loop criteria "i >= 0;"

Comment: @Z_C, do me a favour, in your code after the line `std::string s = "s";` add the line `std::cout << s.size() - 2;`  and see what the result is.

Comment: @anastaciu gets in infinite loop but this time prints the screen full of numbers
Also unless I'm missing something it's not supposed to go beyond zero not because s.size() cannot be negative but because literally that was the criteria of the for loop.

Comment: no, 18446744073709551615

Comment: Oh ok, it's the max value of an 8 byte unsigned long - 1, the principle is the same, you can see now how `i` will never be negative, can you?

Comment: Z_C sorry, I thought you were using `auto i`, so if `i` is `int` my answer doesn´t apply.

Comment: now I tried with auto then int and auto gives infinite loop and/or assertion error and with int it is perfeclty well behaved. idk what's going on... the number is still 18446744073709551615 though

Comment: @Z_C that is to be expected, you still print the value, the assignment to int is narrowing from an unsigned long, it's implementation defined how this should work, but assigning `unsigned long` value `0` to `int` should not be a problem, so it's not clear why your code is doing what it is doing.

Comment: @Z_C use the debugger to track the value of `i` and see where it leads you to.

Comment: @Z_C i.e. place a breakpoint in the line of the for loop run it, and use F10 to step over, you can track i value in the  Locals separator, down bellow.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I misread and was under the impression that OP was using `auto i` so you're right, my diagnosis was incorrect.

Comment: @anastaciu I think you were right to begin with, I think the original may have been a refresh error when I changed around the variable types and it is auto that produces the errors, with int it is fine. With int i is initialized correctly then decreases to 0 then the loop stops. With auto it decreases to zero then flips around to 18446744073709551615 and on and on. So it seems indeed auto assigns unsigned int. 
The only question is why doesn't the loop stop when i becomes 0?

Comment: @Z_C ah, I knew it :D Anyway, joking aside, I'm glad you solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in fact originally caused by "auto" i rather than "int" i, but not properly refreshed. Auto gave i an unsigned int type, which overflowed the [] operator, or caused infinite loop turning over from zero to 18446744073709551615 once the i = 0 cycle completes and i-- is executed.

Thank you everyone for the helpful replies!